# DRF password not being set by set_password()

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I have the following questions:

why isn't the password getting hashed?

why is the password not being set by save_password?

```
platforms = Platform.objects.all()
platforms[2].is_active
>> True
platforms[2].password
>> 'efgh'
platforms[2].check_password("efgh")
>> False
platforms[2].set_password("abcd")
platforms[2].save()
platforms[2].check_password("abcd")
>> False
platforms[2].password
>> 'efgh'
```

**models.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
class Platform(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PlatformSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model  = Platform
        fields = ("username", "password")

        def create(self, validated_data):
            password = validated_data.pop('password')
            platform = Platform(**validated_data)
            platform.set_password(password)
            platform.save()
            return platform
```

**views.py**

```
class CreatePlatform(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset           = Platform.objects.all()
    serializer_class   = PlatformSerializer
    pagination_class   = None
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )
```

in my **settings.py** I have `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.Platform'`

PS: the Token being created just fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p = platforms[2]  
p.set_password("abcd")
p.save()
p.check_password("abcd")
>> True
```

Comment: but what the hell, was this? why wasn't it getting saved the way I did?

Comment: it's because every slice operation does a new query to the database and returns a new object. So the platforms[2] is not connected to subsequent ones.

Comment: wow!! never knew this, could you please point me to some documentation for this? Thank you so much for enlightening me about this

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets
as you can see, every slice hits the db